# Alternative to overwriting the __init__ function of BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python

I would like to define a few variables inside my RequestHandler class that is a subclass of BaseHTTPRequestHandler. These variables then should be accessible from inside my `do_Post()` function. Normaly I would define those variables inside the `__ init__()` method but the [python docs about the BaseHTTPRequestHandler class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

says "Subclasses should not need to override or extend the `__ init__()` method."

So what would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        #do some stuff
```

Comment: If you only want to use them in `do_Post()` can't you just define them there? Otherwise, I misunderstand the question.

Comment: *should not need to* doesn't mean that you can't. Just define the method as `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` and make sure to call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: In fact, the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` implementation doesn't have any `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1):

*Shouldn't need to* means you don't have to worry about that method, the library will work without any special attributes set on the instance. However, that *doesn't mean you can't*.

For example, the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class doesn't define a `__init__` method itself, but the [`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) class in the same module is a direct subclass of `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` which does define an `__init__` method.

Your code can define one just fine:

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # do something with arguments and set state on self

    def do_POST(self):
        # do some stuff
```